# Formatting Proof in Groff

Tags: groff

Is there a way to append a tombstone symbol (usually a square) to the right at the end of line of a proof similar to LaTeX proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My usual solution for this is to specify the margin character at the end of the last line of the proof to be the end-of-proof square in the following way:

```
.mc \(sq 0  \" Specify the square to be placed directly after the end of the current line.
.mc         \" Restore the setting to the previous.
```

You might want to place this in a end-of-proof macro, depending on your troff template.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a string after `.EQ`, (which normally acts as an equation number), to be set on the right hand side.

```
.EQ "\(sq"
inf = - inf
.EN
```

The above produces this
[image: equation]